# Qt Sqlite update returns false

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I have a method that inserts a row and it works fine but my update method returns false at "query.exec()". here my codes. thanx in advance

```
bool DbManager::InsertPerson(QString name,QString surname,int age,QDate birthDate){

    if(openDB()){
        QSqlQuery query;
        query.prepare("INSERT INTO PERSON (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME,AGE,BIRTHDATE) "
                      "VALUES (:FIRSTNAME, :LASTNAME, :AGE, :BIRTHDATE)");
        query.bindValue(":FIRSTNAME", name);
        query.bindValue(":LASTNAME", surname);
        query.bindValue(":AGE", age);
        query.bindValue(":BIRTHDATE",birthDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd").append(" 00:00:00.000"));
        return query.exec();
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool DbManager::UpdatePerson(int id, QString name,QString surname,int age,QDate birthDate){

    if(openDB()){
        QSqlQuery query;
        query.prepare("UPDATE PERSON SET FIRSTNAME:FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME=:LASTNAME,AGE=:AGE,BIRTHDATE=:BIRTHDATE WHERE ID=:ID");
        query.bindValue(":FIRSTNAME", name);//VARCHAR(20)
        query.bindValue(":LASTNAME", surname);//VARCHAR(30)
        query.bindValue(":AGE", age);//INTEGER
        query.bindValue(":BIRTHDATE",birthDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd").append(" 00:00:00.000"));//TEXT:yyyy-MM-dd HH:MI:SS.SSS
        query.bindValue(":ID", id);//INTEGER

        return query.exec();
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: One of these things is not like the other......Is this `FIRSTNAME:FIRSTNAME,` a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the problem. i have to add an "=" before ":" at FIRSTNAME.

UPDATE PERSON SET FIRSTNAME:FIRSTNAME